# Error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty - header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');

Tags: wordpress, plugins, header, php-7

Hello I have this error in my plugin WordPress and the problem is the line code **header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');**

```
public function listPostByCategory(){
    $misc = 'categories';
    $this->buildSitemap( $misc );
    $this->buildSitemapHeader();

    // get all the categories from the database
    $this->categories = get_categories();
            
    // loop through the categries
    foreach($this->categories as $category) {
        
        // setup the cateogory ID
        $cat_id= $category->term_id;

        // Make a header for the cateogry
        //echo '<h2>' . $category->name . '</h2>';

        // create a custom wordpress 
        $args = array(
            'cat' =>  $cat_id
        );
        
        // The Query
        $the_query = new \WP_Query( $args );
        
        // The Loop
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            //echo '<ul>';
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $the_query->the_post();
                    // echo '<li>' . the_permalink() . '</li>';
                    // echo '<hr/>';
                    $this->url = the_permalink();
                    $this->addLink( $this->url );
                }
            //echo '</ul>';
        }    
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    $this->buildFooterSitemap();
}
```

The functions to build the XML file

```
private function buildSitemap( $arg )
{
    header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');

    $filename = '/sitemap-'.$arg.'.xml';
    
    $this->styleSheet = $this->plugin_path . 'xml-sitemap.xls';

    $this->date = wp_date( 'F d, Y h:i:s a' );

    $this->fileSitemap = get_stylesheet_directory() . $filename;

}

private function buildSitemapHeader()
{
    $this->handler = fopen( $this->fileSitemap, "w+" );
    fwrite($this->handler, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'. "\n");
    fwrite($this->handler, '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="' . esc_url( $this->styleSheet ) . '"?>'. "\n");
    fwrite($this->handler, '<!-- generated-on="'. $this->date .'" -->'. "\n");
    fwrite($this->handler, '<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">'. "\n");
}

//private function add($url, $mod, $chfreq, $prio)
private function addLink( $url )
{
    fwrite($this->handler, "\t". '<url>' ."\n");
    fwrite($this->handler, "\t\t". '<loc>'.$url.'</loc>' ."\n");
    fwrite($this->handler, "\t". '</url>'. "\n");
}

private function buildFooterSitemap(){
    fwrite($this->handler, '</urlset>');
    fclose($this->handler);
}
```

If I comment header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8'); on **function buildSitemap** no error appears but all the links appear on the admin page of WordPress. Where is my error?

If I pass into $this->addLink( $this->url ); a simple string no errors appear and no link is writtend in admin panel. I don't understand why **the_permalink()** cause the error

Comment: What does the error say? Headers already sent?

Comment: as I wrote the error is : Error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty. If I comment header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8'); no error appear

Comment: Are you checking the file exists when you call `$this->handler = fopen( $this->fileSitemap, "w+" );` as the `fileSitemap` call is looking for it in the `theme` directory

Comment: in particular the error appear only when I call $this->addLink( $this->url ); on  Wp_Query and I don't understand why... this function creates the body of xml ...

Comment: Ahh i see now, use `get_the_permalink()` not `the_permalink()`, `the_permalink()` echoes the link not returns it, so `$this->url` is always null

Comment: @JoshBonnick I edit the comment and the questions.. the problem is in the function $this->addLink( $this->url )... read my updates

Comment: @JoshBonnick that right! Thank you so much for your helper... It was a stupid error but I'm a novice in WP development. Can I ask you another little answer about WP maybe in private?

Comment: Yeah that's fine. Ask away.

Comment: @JoshBonnick how I can send you a private message?

Comment: err, im not actually sure, just trying to find out now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_permalink()` echoes the value. So it is never assigned to your `$this->url` variable.

You would need to use `get_the_permalink()` to assign it to a variable as this function `returns` the value.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line : header('Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8');

You may see dynamic wordpress sitemap , https://github.com/shantun7792/sitemaps/blob/master/sitemap.php

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. I find the solution with @Josh Bonnick helps